# Enable unlimited scrollback with iTerm2

Tags: terminal, mojave, iterm

I tried to check Unlimited scrollback option in the iTerm2 settings, however, it doesn't seems to be applied for longer outputs (say couple of thousands lines). The output gets truncated so I can scroll up just to the last 1000 lines or so. [image]

I am running Mojave with ZSH 5.7.1 installed, the `HISTSIZE` is set to the 100 000 lines (however I don't think that matters to the terminal emulator). So is there something I am missing? Thanks for help

Comment: Actually I found out it's working for all tabs other than the first one. Which means the first tab still has the limit. Weird :-/

Answer (score 2):

Unlimited scrollback might not work properly as expected, I am not sure why but it is may be because of the config of zsh.

So, I would suggest you specify the scrollback lines like **10000 (in my case)** in the textbox and unchecked the "**unlimited scrollback buffer**" option

[image]